# SSH or VPN for home use to connect to offsite machine for daily backups

Tags: ssh, vpn, backup, openvpn, rsync

I have an Ubuntu server set up at `home1`. I have an Ubuntu client set up at `home2`. I have a script that will do daily rsync backups from `home2` to `home1`.

Right now I have an unobviousness port opened on the router at `home1` that forwards SSH traffic to the server at `home1`. Everything works great. I can do my rsync backups from `home2` to `home1` using ssh.

The router at `home1` offers built in OpenVPN support. It even creates the `.ovpn` config file so all I have to do from `home2` is use it to VPN to `home1`.

So now I am wondering if, for my situation/scenario, is there any benefit to using OpenVPN or is SSH good enough?

Comment: i suppose it's easier to access any server on any machine with a VPN 'cos with ssh you'd have to use a rather longwinded ssh tunneling command to specify exactly which servers you want to access. Whereas with a VPN , once you're connected, you can access whatever server like they're all computers on the same LAN.

Comment: I'm only accessing one server. port forwarding on router forwards to the one server I need.

Comment: Well there's no question that ssh is good enough for you and I think you know that.  I guess ssh has an advantage of a shell built into it